# Crosswordle Puzzle

Tags: word, crosswords, wordle

Billy is not good at Wordle. He insists on guessing words in such a way that the columns form words, too. Here are some crossword-style hints for Billy's words:

[image]

Can you determine the underlying Wordle solution?

For convenience, here are the crossword hints in text format:

```
ACROSS
 1 Happen
 6 Sauce
 7 Inflict
 8 Maxim
 9 Crowbar
10 Outfit

DOWN
 1 Lone gunman?
 2 Someone who processes your Visa?
 3 What Pete did to Kimye?
 4 "Buffalo" has several
 5 Fall guys?
```

Also, here is a numeric encoding of the colors in the grid:

```
00010
10020
00200
00011
01000
00222
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> GUESS

Here is the grid

> ```
>  OCCUR
>  SALSA
>  WREAK
>  ADAGE
>  LEVER
>  DRESS
> ```

Comment: How did you figure out this solution? Can you give some reasoning as to the process in which you came by this/an explanation as to what it means? Thank you.

Comment: @JoeKerr this answer is already good.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Nevermind my comment then, it appears that the OP edited his answer.